# x64 Assembly procedure

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, procedure, masm

suppose that the Entry code in a x64 assembly Procedure is:

```
push  rsi
push  r12
sub   rsp,48
```

now, how can i find each of these value in **body** of PROC :

> 1)1st parameter   2)3rd parameter  3)5th parameter  4)7th parameter

if you can draw  or describe the stack for me, it is very better for me to understand.

Comment: If it is called from some language like C, it would also differ for each OS. What is your platform?

Comment: As Bo Persson says, it depends on the platform. Wikipedia has an article on [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) which covers x64.

Comment: i am in Windows and my cpu is intel family (core i7)

Answer (score 2):

From the [Windows x64 calling conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zthk2dkh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

The first four integer or pointer arguments are passed left to right in `RCX`, `RDX`, `R8`, and `R9`. Once those registers are filled everything else will be on the stack (except the first four floating point arguments).

Since we can't see how the code is called, it's not possible to deduce the arguments from that prologue. You need to look at the code that calls it to find out what will be there, the two `push`es are likely just saving clobbered registers.